# Scala & MongoDB: POJOs and Scala classes

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, pojo

This is written with concern to the MongoDB Java Driver, version `4.2.0-beta`.

Imagine that I have a Mongo Database set up like so:

```
private val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(
MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry,
fromProviders(
  PojoCodecProvider.builder()
    .automatic(true)
    .build()
));
private val client = MongoClients.create(Server.Config.mongoDbConnectionString)
private val database = client.getDatabase("myDatabase").withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
```

Pretty straight-forward so far.

Now imagine that I have `User.scala` that looks like this:

```
case class User(val email: String)
```

Now, let's say say that I have a DB operation executed from a function like this:

```
def CreateUser(document: User): InsertOneResult = {
  val collection = database.getCollection("User", classOf[User])
  collection.insertOne(document)
}
```

All well and good right? Well, actually, no... that gives us a:
`org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class models.User.`

Turns out that the meaning of `POJO` in the `PojoCodecProvider` is quite literal...

If I replace `User.scala` with a `User.java` that looks like this...

```
public class User {
    public String email;
    public String password;
}
```

No more complaints!

I understand that a Scala `class`/`case class` is not a POJO. My question is, how do I go about getting around this limitation? To further complicate things, what if I wanted to make a generic version of the `Create` method given above, like so:

```
def Create[T](document: T)(implicit ctag: ClassTag[T]): InsertOneResult = {
  val collection = getCollection[T]()
  collection.insertOne(document)
}
```

Am I just S.O.L. unless all of my database-stored classes are Java classes?

Comment: Check the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver-scala/getting-started/quick-start-case-class/), they provide some **macros** to create `Codecs` for case classes. - Sadly that won't work for generics unless you register before hand all the codecs you need... the mongo driver could benefit for a more **typeclass** approach but that is another discussion.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejiaSuarez Jeez, I completely missed that section of the docs. Thank you for the link

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejiaSuarez Yeah, `fromProviders(classOf[User])` takes care of it for now. However, as you pointed out, I will need to register all my classes up-front.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I cannot find a better work-around right now, I'll post the one that works.

As @LuisMiguelMejiaSuarez in his comment, the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver-scala/getting-started/quick-start-case-class/) say to register each `class` that you'll need a codec for like so:

```
val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(
    fromProviders(
        classOf[User],
        classOf[MyOtherClass]
    ), 
DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
```

While this *kind-of* complicates my hopes of creating generic CRUD methods, it's still less work than writing custom codecs for each class I wish to store in the DB. Using generic CRUD functions still work with this method, assuming you have the class registered as a codec provider.

Answer (score 0):

Use Macros:

val customCodecs = CodecRegistries.fromProviders(
Macros.createCodecProvider[TargetCaseClass]
)